# apt-get install -f got the error message

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I got this error code when I try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Do anyone know how to fixed it? thanks!

```
$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/36.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 152 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 

(Reading database ... 301192 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.103_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic (3.13.0-63.103) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.103_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.13.0-63-generic/kernel/mm/hwpoison-inject.ko', which is also in package linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic 3.13.0-63.104~precise1

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.103_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Comment: more information: sudo dpkg -C >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 linux-image-generic  Generic Linux kernel image
 linux-generic        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers

Comment: _sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg_ try this @JimmyChen

Comment: more information: sudo apt-get check>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic but it is not installed

Comment: @Ravan got the same error message after command of "sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic "

Comment: change software &updates to main server and try again@JimmyChen

Comment: Fixed it with 2 commands:   sudo dpkg -P linux-image-generic && sudo dpkg -P linux-generic  and  thank you @Ravan

Comment: If those commands fix your problem write in answer and make it solved

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with 2 commands:

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-generic 
sudo dpkg -P linux-generic
```